# Make Jquery image caption and images responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I downloaded and applied this jQuery image caption that slides up on hover however my images are no longer responsive and I've no idea why...

My CSS sets images to have a max-width of 100% but I believe somewhere the JS is overriding it.

http://www.jimharrison.co.uk/

I did create a jsfiddle but couldn't get it to work so probably a bit pointless using it -although all the JS is there so if you look at it you may be able to see why my images aren't being responsive.

http://jsfiddle.net/p3Zm3/

code:

```
<div class="ic_container capslide_img_cont6">
<img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""/>
<div class="overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="ic_caption">
<p class="ic_category">Category</p>
<h3 class="intro">Gallery</h3>
<p class="ic_text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<p class="ic_text"><a href="www.philips.co.uk" class="learn-more">Learn More</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".capslide_img_cont6").capslide({
                caption_color   : 'black',
                caption_bgcolor : 'rgba(255,255,255, 0.6)',
                overlay_bgcolor : 'rgba(255,255,255, 0.3)',
                border          : '0px solid #ccc',
                showcaption     : true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

css:

```
 /* image rule */
img {
border: 0;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
vertical-align:top;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
box-shadow:         0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4);
}


.ic_container {
vertical-align:baseline;;
position:relative;
/*-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-khtml-border-radius:10px;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #888;*/
}

.overlay {
background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);
position:absolute;
top:0px;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=10);
}

.ic_caption {
position:absolute;    
background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.6);   
overflow:hidden;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
cursor:default;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80);
margin-bottom: 1%;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.ic_category {
text-transform:uppercase;
font-size:11px;
letter-spacing:3px;
padding:5px;
margin:0px;
}

.ic_caption h3 {
padding:0px 5px 5px 5px;
margin:0px;
font-size:18px;
}

.ic_text{
padding:5px;
margin:0px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
text-align:left;
font-size:1em;
}

a.learn-more {
padding: 5px 10px;
margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
background: #062d84;    
}

a.learn-more:hover {
color: #062d84; 
background: #ffffff;
}
```

js:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.capslide = function(options) {
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.capslide.defaults, options);
    return this.each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        var o = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $this.data()) : opts;

        if(!o.showcaption)  $this.find('.ic_caption').css('display','none');
        else $this.find('.ic_text').css('display','none');

        var _img = $this.find('img:first');
        var w = _img.css('width');
        var h = _img.css('height');
        $('.ic_caption',$this).css({'color':o.caption_color,'background-color':o.caption_bgcolor,'bottom':'0px','width':w});
        $('.overlay',$this).css('background-color',o.overlay_bgcolor);
        $this.css({'width':w , 'height':h, 'border':o.border});
        $this.hover(
            function () {
                if((navigator.appVersion).indexOf('MSIE 7.0') > 0)
                $('.overlay',$(this)).show();
                else
                $('.overlay',$(this)).fadeIn();
                if(!o.showcaption)
                    $(this).find('.ic_caption').slideDown(500);
                else
                    $('.ic_text',$(this)).slideDown(500);   
            },
            function () {
                if((navigator.appVersion).indexOf('MSIE 7.0') > 0)
                $('.overlay',$(this)).hide();
                else
                $('.overlay',$(this)).fadeOut();
                if(!o.showcaption)
                    $(this).find('.ic_caption').slideUp(200);
                else
                    $('.ic_text',$(this)).slideUp(200);
            }
        );
    });
};
$.fn.capslide.defaults = {
    caption_color   : 'white',
    caption_bgcolor : 'black',
    overlay_bgcolor : 'blue',
    border          : '1px solid #fff',
    showcaption     : true
};
})(jQuery);
```

EDIT:

So after trying to solves the problem myself with still no luck, I've discovered it isn't my images that are not responsive but rather the jQuery is adding inline styles and setting a width and height for the 'ic_container capslide_img_cont6' classes... AAAHHHHH

Comment: I'm not seeing this rule for setting the `max-width` of images...

Comment: It's further up in my CSS - my bad I should have added it in - will do now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WOOOOOP just fixed the problem myself - changed the output to be 'width_%' and 'height_%'.